# finding power of a number

Tags: fpga, exponential, factorization

I have a very big number which is a product of several small primes. I know the number and also I know the prime factors but I don't know their powers. for example:

```
(2^a)x(3^b)x(5^c)x(7^d)x(11^e)x .. = 2310
```

Now I want to recover the exponents in a very fast and efficient manner. I want to implement it in an FPGA.

Regards,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show us your attempt at the solution. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: what i have tried is to divide the number by its prime factors iteratively unitl i get a fraction. then i will count the number of divisions for each factor which gives me the powers. but this is not practical when the product becomes very huge as i mentioned.

Comment: if you iteratively divide 2310 by 2 more than 'a' times, you will end up with some fraction number. but until 'a', you will get 0 fractions. so counting will help, but it's too slow.

Comment: Why do you want to implement in FPGA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing a linear search for the right power when you should be doing a binary search. Below is an example showing how to the case where the power of p is 10 (p^10). This method finds the power in O(log N) divisions rather than O(N).

First find the upper limit by increasing the power quickly until it's too high, which happens at step 5. Then it uses a binary search to find the actual power.

1. Check divisibility by p. Works.
2. Check divisibility by p^2. Works.
3. Check divisibility by p^4. Works.
4. Check divisibility by p^8. Works.
5. Check divisibility by p^16. Doesn't work. Undo/ignore this one.
6. Check divisibility by p^((8+16)/2)=p^12. Doesn't work. Undo/ignore this one.
7. Check divisibility by p^((8+12)/2)=p^10. Works, but might be too low.
8. Check divisibility by p^((10+12)/2)=p^11. Doesn't work. Undo/ignore this one.
9. Since ((10+11)/2)=10.5 is not an integer, the power most be the low end, which is 10.

Note, there is a method where you actually divide by p, and at step 4, you've actually divided the number by p^(1+2+4+8)=p^15, but it's a bit more difficult to explain the binary search part. However, the size of the number being divided gets smaller, so division operations are faster.